# Parsing JSON Arrays - Placing result into HTML <span>

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

I am trying to parse a JSON file from URL and then take some of the information from the JSON and place into my site. I have succeeded in doing this for simple JSON files with no complex array/object structure.

I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong here but any help or advice is appreciated, if anyone could point me to a good write up on JSON structure that would also be appreciated, struggling to find any information which involves taking selective data from JSON files.

Relevant JSON file can be found here: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=1

The exact information I'm looking for is game under streams.

HTML:

```
<p><span id="game"></span></p>
```

Script:

```
var url2 = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=1";
$.getJSON(url2 + "?callback=?", null, function (topdata) {
document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = topdata.streams[0].game;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url2 already has a query part. Sou adding the query for the callback starting with "?" brings a second query part and therefore it is not evaluated. change the "?" to "&" and it works:

```
var url2 = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=1";
$.getJSON(url2 + "&callback=?", null, function (topdata) {
    document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = topdata.streams[0].game;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E7SM9/

Comment: Thank you so much, the amount of time I have spent trying to fix this is fairly embarrassing for how simple the answer was. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var jsonObject = eval(jsonString);
```

to turn json string back to JSON object

and also consider changing your getJson to:

```
$.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: your request url,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      });
```